# Как получить определенные ячейки таблицы PDF в Python?

Tags: python, парсер, pdf

Хочу создать бота для телеги, который будет парсить с сайта колледжа PDF файлы с расписанием. Возник вопрос как найти нужные мне ячейки (всегда одинаковые, не меняются изо дня в день) с моей группой. Возможно это получится сделать путем конвертации PDF в CSV и там уже по координатам ячейки найти нужные. Но как это реализовать? Через какие библиотеки? Или может возможно делать скрин определенной области PDF файла, в которую будет попадать моя группа?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [это](https://fedingo.com/how-to-convert-pdf-to-csv-in-python/), должно помочь. Вам понадобится tabula-py, данный модуль поможет превратить PDF файлы в CSV.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).